# How to retrieve text from JSON and display the text in point form (ReactJS Hook)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I was able to retrieve JSON data via an API. However, I'm would like to know how I could retrieve my JSON data and display the output via a point form (example shown below). If anyone know how, please teach me. Much appreciate.

**Code: Calling API**

```
const [getText, setText] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
    const url = "API link"

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(json[0]["results");
            getText(json.[0]["results"];
        }catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error)
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

**JSON File Format**

```
"results": [
             {
               item_class_1: "class1"
               item_value_1: "value1"
               item_name_1: "name1"
             }
             {
               item_class_2: "class2"
               item_value_2: "value2"
               item_name_2: "name2"
             }
                .
                .
                .
           ]
```

**Expected Output in HTML:**

```
class1: value1, name1
class2: value2, name2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the response data of API in the state by `setText` as shown below:-

```
const [getText, setText] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const url = "API link"

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try{
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log(json[0]["results");
            setText(json.[0]["results"];
        }catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error)
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Now you can access the API response by calling getText and display the data as shown below:-

```
return (
      <>
      <h1>lakjdfkds</h1>
        {this.state.data.map((item) => {
          let values = Object.values(item)
          return(
            <>
            {values[0]}: {values[1]}, {values[2]}<br/>
            </>

          )
        })}
      </>
    )
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can I ask where do I call the getText ? do I replace data.map with getText.map ?

Comment: These both code snippet are from the same component, in which this getText is defined. you can access the "getText" in the component and add the following functionality mentioned above to get the particular format of data from the API response data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've managed to print out my text. Appreciate alot.